# Cannot find my lvm structure anymore : sudo pvs from CD/ISO shows nothing

Tags: 22.04, lvm, recovery-mode

a collegue crashed the LVM structure of a VM so I'm trying to help him repair the LVM structure.

I first tried to boot into recovery mode but I end up in a busybox shell.

So I rebooted into an Ubuntu 22.04 ISO and then I try to scan the LVM structure :

```shell
$ sudo pvscan
$ sudo pvs
$
```

But it shows nothing, how can I fix this ?